# Is there a bug on Scala's @transient?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, inheritance

I have a code structure like the following.

```
trait Document {
  def name: String
  @transient lazy val formalName = "FORMAL " + name
}

object XFile extends Document {
  override val name = "XFILE"
}
```

But spark is throwing an `java.io.NotSerializableException` on `XFile`

I saw this [scala bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1573?orig=1) marked as fix. But their code is slightly difference.

I am currently using Scala 2.11, but their bug is fixed on 2.8.

Is this possibly a new bug? Or I am just using transient incorrectly?

Comment: What does `transient` has to do with `XFile` simply not being `serializable` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-

Comment: why dont you try serializing XFile   or Document?

Comment: Thank you both very much. It indeed solved the problem by extending Serializable.
But mind explaining what does Serializable actually does? And what is serializing actually doing? Is it just sending the opcode directly to the workers?
I am fairly new to programming, any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Making XFile `Serializable` should solve your problem

```
object XFile extends Document with Serializable {
```

Comment: Hmm.. ok, indeed it does. But would you mind explaining why? I am fairly new to programming, so what does `Serializable` actually does? And what is serializing actually doing? Is it just sending the opcode directly to the workers?

Comment: By default the classes are not serializable except the case classes in scala. For more on serializable look here : https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-serialization-in-scala-serializable-trait